# Error in Sklearn MinMaxScaler Normalization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

Check the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x = np.array([[-1, 4, 2], [-0.5, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_train_norm = scaler.fit_transform(x_train.T).T
x_test_norm = scaler.transform(x_test.T).T
```

It throws the following error:

```
x_test_norm = scaler.transform(x_test.T).T
ValueError: X has 1 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 2 features as input.
```

The error is pretty clear, but i am unsure how to fix it. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I need the normalization to be performed in the transposed data (i.e, at each row independently). That is why i have transposed it.

Answer (score 0):

The scaler is first fit on x_test.T, which has shape (3,2). Therefore it needs an input on shape (n, 2) to transform, as it has been fit to transform this shape. x_train.T is shape (3,1), which gives the error.

I would suggest dropping the Transposes, which removes the error, but i am unsure if it is what you intend:

```
x_train_norm = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_norm = scaler.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: The normalization should be performed at each row independently, that is why i have transposed it.